# Hide a row based on a condition in WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server

My title might be confusing, so I'll try to explain the best I can.

I have two tables

LEFT: table `numbers` RIGHT: table `contracts`:

[image]

I want to show, for each instance where there's a `number` associated to the contract and it is started with `9` to have it's own row, changing the value of `accessID` to that number. And if the number is started with `2` it doesn't change the `accessID` value, but adds it to the phone column.

[image]

My code is

```
SELECT CASE WHEN n.number LIKE '9%' THEN n.number ELSE c.accessID END accessID
        , c.client client
        , '' stat
        , '' phone
    FROM numbers n
    JOIN contracts c ON c.contractID = n.contractID
    WHERE n.number LIKE '9%'
UNION
SELECT c.accessID accessID
        , c.client client
        , c.stat stat
        , CASE WHEN n.number LIKE '2%' THEN n.number ELSE '' END phone
    FROM contracts c
    LEFT JOIN numbers n ON n.contractID = c.contractID
ORDER BY client
```

On this case I want to hide the row that's highlighted, but if I add `WHERE n.number LIKE '2%'` after the `LEFT JOIN` it would hide every row where the `accessID` doesn't start with `9` and doesn't have any value in `phone`.

I've also tried this, but with no luck

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT n.number FROM numbers n where n.number like '2%')
```

Comment: Why do you want `Leon` twice if you don't want `Mary` three times?

Comment: `Leon` has a number started with `9`, so he will appear twice, note that on the `accessID` column the values are different, for `Leon`, but with `Mary`, there's two rows with the same value.

Comment: I always want to show one row for each, then only if they have a number started with `9` I want to show another row.

Comment: Please, post the sample data as DDL & DML or formatted text so people can copy/paste it for testing and brings an answer to you. Images won't help others to help you.

Comment: You can use this link to [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=afcff96d5cf02d067e8ceb2c785a4da4) with the query and tables all set up

Comment: _"Leon has a number started with 9, so he will appear twice"_ So why `Tony` appears just 1 time while his number starts with `9`? Your question isn't clear at all.

Comment: My bad, didn't put the row on my example, it was meant to appear, I updated it so it appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this you need?

```
SELECT CASE WHEN n.number LIKE '9%' THEN n.number ELSE c.accessID END accessID, c.client client, '' stat, '' phone
    FROM numbers n
    JOIN contracts c ON c.contractID = n.contractID
    WHERE n.number LIKE '9%'
UNION
SELECT l.accessID,l.client,l.stat,l.phone FROM (
SELECT c.accessID accessID, c.client client, c.stat stat, CASE WHEN n.number LIKE '2%' THEN n.number ELSE '' END phone
,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY n.contractID,c.stat ORDER BY n.number) AS LineID
FROM contracts c
LEFT JOIN numbers n ON n.contractID = c.contractID
) AS l WHERE l.LineID=1
ORDER BY client
```

accessID    client     stat       phone

---

134568792   John       scheduled  246875183
141574896   Leon       installed  0
967664616   Leon                  0
139874521   Mary       cancelled  225496825
914568598   Mary                  0
140410591   Tony       installed  0
918264829   Tony                  0